# how to dynamically set an array object into input field in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please i am trying to dynamically set array object into input field and send it to the backend. thanks

when i console.log printOut, it return undifined.
hi everyone, please i am trying to dynamically set array object into input field and send it to the backend. thanks

hi everyone, please i am trying to dynamically set array object into input field and send it to the backend. thanks

```
const myArr= [
        {product: 'egg', price: 5, id:1},
        {product: 'cake', price: 3, id:2}
    ]

    const [input, setInput] = useState(myArr)


      const changeHandler = (id) => event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setInput(input => input.map((el) => el.id === id
          ? {
              ...el,
              [name]: value,
            }
          : el,
        ));
      };

    const submitForm = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        
        let printOut = input
            
        
        console.log({print:printOut});
        try {
            axios.post('/products/print', printOut)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
            {myArr.map(x=>(
                <div key={x.id}>
                    <input name='product' value= {x.product} onChange={(e) =>changeHandler(x.id)(e)}  />
                    <input name='price' value= {x.price} onChange={(e)=> changeHandler(x.id)(e)} />
                    
                </div>
            ))}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    )
```

Comment: Is not your `x.id` undefined?

Comment: `input` is an array but you're trying to access it like an object `input.product`.

Comment: Your onChange event should be ‘onChange={(e) => changeHander(x.I’d)(e) }’ . Your changeHandler returns a function. I think it’s called currying but it’s a function returning another function.

Comment: thanks Andy, please how can i access it like an array and again i got an empty data in the database

Comment: thanks joseph, i have modified it and i still got undefined error

Comment: hi, Khalt, thanks for your comment. please i didnt understand your question.

Comment: Your array is not showing the id that you are using while mapping. And like Andy said.. input is assumed to be an array but used like an object.

Comment: Console.log(input) will give you more clarity. You may update your code with new fixes.

Comment: @Sanish Joseph console.log(input) returns empty array

Comment: Your changeHandler is still not correct. Read my comment and correct it.

Comment: i have modified it now. and its still the same error. thanks

Comment: myArr has no id. Where are you getting the id from?

Comment: thanks . it shows only the first object in the array when console

Comment: Your `setInput(input => input.map((el) => el.id === id
          ? {
              ...el,
              [name]: value,
            }
          : el,
        ));` is also wrong. `input.map` will never work as you have set initial state fro that as `[]`. Now I don't know what you will need but, either update initial state to myArray or change setState mapping to myArray like `setInput(input => myArray.map((el) => el.id === id
          ? {
              ...el,
              [name]: value,
            }
          : el,
        ));`

Comment: thanks Joseph. both the console and the backend is now working very fine. im so grateful to you and everyone. cheers!!!

Comment: Great. I will add it as an answer. To earn some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the chat, there were plenty of issues.

1. handleChange call was not correct. Your onChange event should be `onChange={(e) => changeHander(x.id)(e) }` . Your `changeHandler` returns a function. I think it’s called `currying` but it’s a function returning another function.
2. Your `setInput(input => input.map((el) => el.id === id? {...el, [name]: value,} : el,));` is also wrong. `input.map` will never work as you have set initial state for that as []. Now I don't know what you will need but, either update initial state to `myArray` or change setState mapping to myArray like `setInput(input => myArray.map((el) => el.id === id? { ...el, [name]: value,}  : el,));`